# Using the apply function on rows of a data.frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame:

`df<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c('b','a','c'))`

If I type:

`as.character(df[1,])`

I get:

`"1" "2"`

Or if I type:

`paste(df[1,],collapse=':')`

I get:

`1:2`

But, if I type:

`apply(df,1,as.character)`  or `apply(df,1,paste,collapse=':')`

I get:

```
[1,] "1"  "2"  "3" 
[2,] "b"  "a"  "c"
```

and

```
"1:b" "2:a" "3:c"
```

I assumed that running the apply function would coerce each row of the df to a vector and then apply the function e.g. as.character() or paste()

However this does not seem to be the case. Can someone please explain what is happening in apply in this situation and why it gives a different answer to the below:

`paste(df[1,],collapse=":")` then `paste(df[2,],collapse=":")` then `paste(df[3,],collapse=":")`

Comment: `apply` converts to a matrix and matrix can have only a single type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the string columns are `factor` class because while constructing the `data.frame`, the default option is `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` and the `factor` would get coerced to integer storage mode when we do `paste` across columns.  To avoid this behavior use

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c('b','a','c'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

paste(df[1,],collapse=":")
#[1] "1:b"
```

---

With `apply`, it converts to `matrix` and matrix can have only a single class, therefore it converts the numeric to 'character' when there is a character element based on the precedence of class

Comment: Thank you, the key was the fact that apply first converts to matrix, which I wasn't aware of. Can I ask, when you perform the command ```as.matrix(df)``` how come it sees the the factor as character and not integer? I ask because I was told that if I tried to vectorise the first row e.g. ```as.vector(df[1,])``` it would coerce the factor to integer? I can post a new question if needed

Comment: @ASam Because the attributes are stripped off and you get only the string there.  If the attributes are present, it would get converted i.e. try `as.integer(factor(letters[c(1:5, 3:5)]))` , here it is coerced to integer storage values, but if the same gets converted to matrix, the attributes are stripped off `matrix(factor(letters[c(1:5, 3:5)]), ncol = 2)`

Comment: The `as.vector(df[1,])` is not converting to vector as it is still a data.frame.  You need `unlist` or first convert to `character` class and then do `unlist`. i.e. `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character); unlist(df[1,])`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the the explanation by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60792271/12158757) might be already quite clear to you, where the issue is caused by `factor` when you try `paste(df[1,],collapse=":")`.

Here is an alternative that can circumvent the issue, that is, using

```
do.call(paste,c(df,sep = ":"))[1]
```

for your objective, such that

```
> do.call(paste,c(df,sep = ":"))[1]
[1] "1:b"
```

Comment: Yes Akrun's answer helped a lot. This is also useful but  why does ```do.call``` work in this instance? Does it also first convert ```df``` to a matrix, like ```apply```? I read that ```do.call``` "constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it". Here, ```paste``` is the function and the arguments are ```df``` and ```sep=":"``` but why does this syntax produce a very different output compared to ```paste(df,sep=":")```.

Comment: @ASam You can check `?paste`. `paste` first convert columns to characters and then concatenate them. I used `do.call` is to only for shortening my code